# Not Retaining letters in display each keyup (pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, decode

I'm making a caesar decoding feature but every time I change the letter the display is not retaining, I need to retain the previous letters in dom, how can I make that happen with most minimal change in my code

```js
var max = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var input = document.querySelector('#un');
input.addEventListener("keyup", caesar)

function caesar() {
  var userpref = 1
  var joe = max.split("")
  var text = document.querySelector('#un').value;
  var textlet = Array.of(...text);
  var num = joe.indexOf(textlet[textlet.length - 1]) + userpref
  var fin = joe[num]
  var decoded = document.querySelector('#decoded').innerHTML = fin;

}
```

```html
<input id="un" type="text">
<div id="decoded"></div>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow ...  "with the minimal change in my code": change `=` to `+=` in the `var decode` line :)

Comment: thank you so much!, i dont know thats possible, you save me from another hour of figuring it out 

Comment: It's called [concatenation](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/operators/string-operator.php) and it's an abbreviation: `a = a + 1` would simply be written as `a += 1`

Comment: I just realize another problem, whenever i press backspace the display its not deleting, how can i fix this?

Comment: so, you simply need to check if user pressed delete key and update, for example, remove the last char of `#decoded` ... you can also block some keys, like left and right ... there are so many possibilities :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the snipped to work below:

Just add a `+` to concatenate the string.

```js
var max = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var input = document.querySelector('#un');
input.addEventListener("keyup", caesar)

function caesar() {
  var userpref = 1
  var joe = max.split("")
  var text = document.querySelector('#un').value;
  var textlet = Array.of(...text);
  var num = joe.indexOf(textlet[textlet.length - 1]) + userpref
  var fin = joe[num]
  var decoded = document.querySelector('#decoded').innerHTML += fin; // add this plus here!

}
```

```html
<input id="un" type="text">
<div id="decoded"></div>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: yea thanks!but whenever i press backspace the display its not deleting, how can i fix this?